# Horizontal spacing in aligned equations

Tags: support, mathjax

For [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/455625/35416) I'd like to align some euqations so that matching terms are arranged in columns. But both alternatives that I could think of didn't work as intended:

Using `\begin{array}{rlcrrrrrrr}` I get too much space between the columns, i,.e. in front of the operators:

$$\begin{array}{rlcrrrrrrr}
\exp(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!} &=& 1 &+ x &+ \frac{x^2}{2!} &+ \frac{x^3}{3!} &+ \frac{x^4}{4!} &+ \frac{x^5}{5!} &+ \cdots \\
\sin(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} &=&& x &&- \frac{x^3}{3!} &&+ \frac{x^5}{5!} &- \cdots \\
\cos(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!} &=& 1 &&- \frac{x^2}{2!} &&+ \frac{x^4}{4!} &&- \cdots
\end{array}$$

Using `\begin{alignat*}{9}` I get too little space. Apparently my operators don't get the spacing they usually do.

\begin{alignat*}{9}
\exp(x) &\,= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!} &=& 1 &+& x &+& \frac{x^2}{2!} &+& \frac{x^3}{3!} &+& \frac{x^4}{4!} &+& \frac{x^5}{5!} &+& \;\cdots \\
\sin(x) &\,= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} &=&&& x &&&-& \frac{x^3}{3!} &&&+& \frac{x^5}{5!} &-& \;\cdots \\
\cos(x) &\,= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!} &=& 1 &&&-& \frac{x^2}{2!} &&&+& \frac{x^4}{4!} &&&-& \;\cdots
\end{alignat*}

If this were $\LaTeX$, I'd use `@{}` in or `@{\,}` in the `array` approach, but MathJax does not seem to understand this.

Is there a way to obtain this level of control over the horizontal spacing of custom-aligned equations, without placing all the `\,` manually on both sides of each operator?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not with `alignat`, which by design doesn't add any extra spaces, and is precisely what you want. The problem is that your way of using `alignat` forces the binary operators `+` and `-` to be interpreted as  ordinary characters instead of binary operators which includes appropriate spacing.

You wrote

```
\begin{alignat*}{9}
\exp(x) &\,= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!} &=& 1 &+& x &+&
\frac{x^2}{2!} &+& \frac{x^3}{3!} &+& \frac{x^4}{4!} &+&
\frac{x^5}{5!} &+& \;\cdots \\
\sin(x) &\,= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} &=&&& x
&&&-& \frac{x^3}{3!} &&&+& \frac{x^5}{5!} &-& \;\cdots \\
\cos(x) &\,= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!} &=& 1 &&&-&
\frac{x^2}{2!} &&&+& \frac{x^4}{4!} &&&-& \;\cdots
\end{alignat*}
```

The simplest way to get what you want is to write

```
\begin{alignat*}{7}
\exp(x) &\,= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!} && = 1 & {}+ x && {} +
\frac{x^2}{2!} && {}+ \frac{x^3}{3!} && {}+ \frac{x^4}{4!} && {}+
\frac{x^5}{5!} && {} + \cdots \\
\sin(x) &\,= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} && =&
x
&&&&{} - \frac{x^3}{3!} &&&&{} + \frac{x^5}{5!} &&{} - \cdots \\
\cos(x) &\,= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!} &&= 1 &&&{} -
\frac{x^2}{2!} &&&&{} + \frac{x^4}{4!} &&&&{} - \cdots
\end{alignat*}
```

The empty object `{}` asks the parser to interpret the `+` sign following it  (which is itself followed by a variable) as a mathematical binary operator, and this way the proper spacing for a binary operator is generated.

Here are the outputs as compiled by TeXLive 2012
[image]

And here's the corresponding renderings in MathJax

\begin{alignat*}{9}
\exp(x) &\,= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!} &=& 1 &+& x &+&
\frac{x^2}{2!} &+& \frac{x^3}{3!} &+& \frac{x^4}{4!} &+&
\frac{x^5}{5!} &+& \;\cdots \\
\sin(x) &\,= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} &=&&& x
&&&-& \frac{x^3}{3!} &&&+& \frac{x^5}{5!} &-& \;\cdots \\
\cos(x) &\,= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!} &=& 1 &&&-&
\frac{x^2}{2!} &&&+& \frac{x^4}{4!} &&&-& \;\cdots
\end{alignat*}

\begin{alignat*}{7}
\exp(x) &\,= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!} && = 1 & {}+ x && {} +
\frac{x^2}{2!} && {}+ \frac{x^3}{3!} && {}+ \frac{x^4}{4!} && {}+
\frac{x^5}{5!} && {} + \cdots \\
\sin(x) &\,= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} && =&
x
&&&&{} - \frac{x^3}{3!} &&&&{} + \frac{x^5}{5!} &&{} - \cdots \\
\cos(x) &\,= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!} &&= 1 &&&{} -
\frac{x^2}{2!} &&&&{} + \frac{x^4}{4!} &&&&{} - \cdots
\end{alignat*}

Comment: I'm not sure I consider adding `{}` that much easier than the `\,` I mentioned in my question, but I agree that it is conceptually cleaner. I've used this approach for now, but somehow I still hope someone might come up with an even more elegant solution…

Comment: @MvG: the advantage is that with `{}` you are being consistent: if someone changes the spacing used for binary operators your entire expression will change in the same way. If you code in the `\,` ad hoc it "may" break. Of course, in practice this kind of situation is almost never a problem.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative that I'm pretty sure you won't like is to use `\phantom` to leave space for the missing terms (rather than use an array).  E.g.

```
\begin{alignat*}{1}
    \exp(x) &{} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!} &{} = 
    1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} +
       \frac{x^5}{5!} + \cdots \\
    \sin(x) &{} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} &{} =
    \phantom{1 +{}} x \phantom{{}+ \frac{x^2}{2!}} - \frac{x^3}{3!}
       \phantom{{}+ \frac{x^4}{4!}} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \cdots \\
    \cos(x) &{} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!} &{} = 
    1 \phantom{{}+ x} - \frac{x^2}{2!} \phantom{{}+ \frac{x^3}{3!}} +
       \frac{x^4}{4!} \phantom{{}+ \frac{x^5}{5!}} - \cdots
    \end{alignat*}
```

You do need to use the `{}` trick to make the phantomed `+` signs be binary rather than unary ones.

\begin{alignat*}{1}
\exp(x) &{} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!} &{} = 
1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} +
   \frac{x^5}{5!} + \cdots \\
\sin(x) &{} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} &{} =
\phantom{1 +{}} x \phantom{{}+ \frac{x^2}{2!}} - \frac{x^3}{3!}
   \phantom{{}+ \frac{x^4}{4!}} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \cdots \\
\cos(x) &{} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!} &{} = 
1 \phantom{{}+ x} - \frac{x^2}{2!} \phantom{{}+ \frac{x^3}{3!}} +
   \frac{x^4}{4!} \phantom{{}+ \frac{x^5}{5!}} - \cdots
\end{alignat*}